# Connection closed in rabbitmq for some reason after some time

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm using pika python library to connect to rabbitmq-server on localhost.

```
class BaseRabbitSender(MessageSender):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host):
        self.node = BaseMessagingNode(host)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=host))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

    @abstractmethod
    def send_message(self, message):
        pass

    def close_connection(self):
        self.connection.close()


class DirectRabbitSender(BaseRabbitSender):
    def __init__(self, host, queue_name):
        super(DirectRabbitSender, self).__init__(host)
        self.queue_name = queue_name
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True)

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                   routing_key=self.queue_name,
                                   body=message,
                                   properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                       delivery_mode=2,
                                   ))

    def close_connection(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

For some reason after quite time (like couple of days) I'm getting error.

```
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 560, in basic_publish
    (properties, body), False)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1147, in _send_method
    self.connection.send_method(self.channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 267, in send_method
    self._send_method(channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/connection.py", line 1504, in _send_method
    self._send_frame(frame.Header(channel_number, length, content[0]))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 410, in _send_frame
    self.process_data_events()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 236, in process_data_events
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
ConnectionClosed
```

Rabbitmq server log

```
=INFO REPORT==== 3-Mar-2014::15:11:03 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.26625.0> (127.0.0.1:41846 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Mar-2014::15:38:12 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.326.0> (127.0.0.1:58580 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{heartbeat_timeout,running}

=WARNING REPORT==== 3-Mar-2014::16:11:04 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.26625.0> (127.0.0.1:41846 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 3-Mar-2014::16:11:05 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.27016.0> (127.0.0.1:37776 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Mar-2014::17:41:05 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.27016.0> (127.0.0.1:37776 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{heartbeat_timeout,running}
```

It's running on ubuntu 13.10. RabbitMQ 3.1.3

I don't understand what happened. Can you explain?

Comment: it always a good idea to post some platform info, versions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the actual problem was that I've stopped rabbitmq-server. And pika doesn't deal with disconnects.

Answer (score 3):

Relevant log line: {heartbeat_timeout,running}.

Something prevents BlockingConnection from sending heartbeats, so RabbitMQ considers your client unreachable or dead. You have 3 options:

- Avoid the blocking behaviour
- Increase heartbeat interval
- Try alternative connection implementations, e.g. Tornado.

Answer (score 1):

I had some tests that I want to run. Everything is fine when I run it in my localhost. But, when I run the tests in a server, I had exactly the same problem and situation as this one. I checked my `pika` version, it's `0.9.13`. I'm using `BlockingConnection` too, by the way.

First, I tried to call `process_data_events()` periodically. It didn't work.
Second, I tried to open a new connection and channel whenever I publish a message or open a new queue. It didn't work.
Third, I tried to upgrade `pika` to `0.9.14`. It didn't work.

Somebody on a thread here: https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/397 mentioned the possibility of a `socket` bug. So, I checked the python version, hypothesizing that maybe there IS a bug, and it was fixed in the later version of python. In the server, the python version is `2.7.3`, and in my localhost it's `2.7.12`. To test if python version is really the problem, I installed [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) and created an environment with python version `2.7.3`. I ran the tests and it passed (I can't reproduce the issue).

After all of the above attempts, I came up with another hypothesis that maybe it's a bug in my server's `rabbitmq-server`. I compared the versions: in localhost it's the latest (`3.6.5`), in my server it's `2.8.4`. To verify that this is the actual problem, I ran the tests, but I used a remote rabbitmq with a later version. Everything worked fine. So, I upgraded the `rabbitmq-server` and, lo and behold, the problem disappears!

**TL;DR:**
The solution is to upgrade your `rabbitmq-server`!